# Dimension(s) concept - is there a difference in meanings?

Tags: linear-algebra

In physics, a vector (say p) is in 3D when it has 3 components.

In linear algebra, a matrix (say Q) made of 2 vectors (say v and w) is

1. 2D when v and w are independent.
2. 1D when two vectors are dependent.
3. 0D when both are zero vectors.

It does not matter how many components (say 75) they have.

why is there such a difference in meaning? is anyone wrong.

Comment: Think about the spaces generated by independent vectors and dependent ones, let's say the pair (1,0) and (0,1) and the pair (1,0), (2,0), what dimensions do they have?

Comment: In linear algebra, "dimension" is not an attribute of an individual vector, but rather of a *collection* of vectors.  We talk of the "dimension of a vector space", not the dimension of the elements in it.

Comment: Think about the set of all vectors generated by linear combinations of the rows of the matrix. How "big" is that set? That's what the dimension of the matrix is.

Comment: I see it that way. If you have a set of vectors of 500 coordinates, but it is dimension 2, it is because you have a lot of "junk", "useless" coordinates. Since these can be obtained from 2. The only thing that really matters is the amount of free addresses you have (coordinates) and not the variety you have when combining them (combine = linearly dependent)

Comment: Frankly, I've NEVER seen a matrix referred to as "3D", "2D", or "1D".  Where did you see that?

Comment: @mweiss $v = [1 2 3]^T$ is a 3-D vector.

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH sure, but that's useless information.  There is no intrinsic mathematical property that an individual "3D" vector has that distinguishes it from an individual "2D" vector.

Comment: @mweiss is $w=[1 2]^T$ same as $v=[1 2 3]^T$ . i dont think so.

Comment: Of course they are not the same thing. But the difference is immaterial. What property does one have that the other lacks?

Comment: i dont know but one can be porperly defined by 2 cordinates, but the other needs 3 coordinates. they both may define the same point but in different ways. _so that would mean that dimension (for a vector) is basically a way of defining._

Comment: @mweiss is exactly right and their first comment could be the answer. It is meaningless to talk about the dimension of a vector. One requires to consider the dimension of the vector space itself. One could easily have the object $[1\,2]^T$ in a non-$2D$ space e.g. $\{ [1\,a]^T:a\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is a $1D$ space.

Comment: yes @epiliam but $[1 a]^T$ is a 1D subspace(representing a line) in 2D Vector Space($R^2$ not $R^3$ not $R^1$) so there is something missing (or i dont know).

Comment: @VIVEKSINGH You could also have $\{[a\,b]^T:a,b\in\mathbb{C}\}$ which is four dimensional over the reals. You could also consider it as a constant element of an infinite dimensional function space. You could really do anything. Without the underlying vector space structure defined you cannot talk about dimension.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing 3 things which speaking loosely can be called dimensions. And you do seem to be speaking loosely (not too rigorously in math sense).

1. dimension of a vector - the number of its components/elements
2. dimension(s) of a matrix - it is just the pair of two natural numbers $(n, m)$ which says how many rows/columns that matrix has
3. rank of a matrix - the dimension of the vector space generated by its rows/columns

That's where your confusion comes from.

Comment: "Dimension of a matrix" is rather called *rank*.

Comment: @Berci Yeah, thanks.

Comment: @peter.petrov A=[1 2; 2 6] and B=[1 2 3; 2 4 8; 1 2 3] represent a plane both have same rank (=2). but A in is 2D space while B is in 3D space. is it not? then what is D here, are we speaking loosely?

Comment: It is more right to say: the rows of A are two-dimensional vectors and the rows of B are three dimensional vectors. The concepts 2D and 3D is used in IT/software world but not in math. You are mixing up software, linear algebra, analytic geometry, physics in some interesting way :) Yes, in some sense both define planes but they are completely different beasts.